# How to generate digital signature with PL/SQL when upgrade Google map service from v2 to v3?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoding-api

```
I tried to generate digital signature for Google map service

 Maps for Business: Generating Valid Signatures - YouTube

Generating an HMAC-SHA-1 Signature Using Only PL/SQL

  OAuth and the PL/SQL | Data Warehouse in the Cloud
```

but I got error message from Google:

Unable to authenticate the request. Provided 'signature' is not valid for the provided client ID. Learn more: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/webservices/auth

I think there is something wrong with my code to generate signature, as if I remove the part regarding client and signature, it will work, can anyone help me on this problem?

```
/*Procedure Get_Geocoding is used to get geocoding with accuracy level for V3 business account, you can find Google map digital signature descrirption from
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/webservices/auth#digital_signatures
if geocoding is 0,0, procedure returns false to indicate failure of get geocoding*/

procedure Get_Geocoding2(P_s_Address in varchar2, P_s_Geocoding out varchar2, P_n_accuracy out number, P_b_success out boolean) is



  --private key for Google business account, this is provided by Google with client name.

  l_private_key_src varchar2(200):='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

  l_private_key_b64_alter varchar2(200):= translate(l_private_key_src,'-_','+/');

  l_private_key_bin raw(2000);

  l_client_name varchar2(100):='gme-xxx';



  l_signature_mac raw(2000);

  l_signature_b64 varchar2(200);

  l_signature_b64_alter_back varchar2(200);



  l_Google_service_domain varchar2(200):='http://maps.googleapis.com';



  l_address varchar2(4000);

  l_url varchar2(32000);

  l_path varchar2(32000);

  l_response varchar2(32000);

  l_page UTL_HTTP.HTML_PIECES;



  n_actual_length number;

  json_obj json;

  json_tempobj json;

  jl_listOfValues json_list;

  json_geom_obj json;

  json_loc json;



  l_lat  VARCHAR2(40);

  l_lng  VARCHAR2(40);

  l_status VARCHAR2(255);

  json_accuracy json;



  --temp_string varchar2(10000);



  n_first_comma number;

  n_second_comma number;

  n_level_length number;



  BEGIN
    /* TODO implementation required */


    l_private_key_bin := utl_encode.base64_decode(UTL_I18N.string_to_raw(l_private_key_b64_alter, 'AL32UTF8'));

    l_address:=APEX_UTIL.URL_ENCODE(P_s_Address);
    --dbms_output.put_line(l_address);
    l_address := replace(l_address,' ','+');
    l_path := '/maps/api/geocode/json?address='||l_address||'&'||'sensor=true';
    dbms_output.put_line(l_path);

    l_signature_mac :=DBMS_CRYPTO.mac(UTL_I18N.string_to_raw(l_path, 'AL32UTF8'), DBMS_CRYPTO.hmac_sh1,l_private_key_bin);


    l_signature_b64:= UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2(UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode(l_signature_mac));
    l_signature_b64_alter_back:=translate(l_signature_b64,'+/','-_');
    dbms_output.put_line(l_signature_b64_alter_back);


    --get response from Google map service
    l_url:=l_Google_service_domain||l_path||'&client='||l_client_name||'&signature='||l_signature_b64_alter_back;
    --l_url:=l_Google_service_domain||l_path;
    dbms_output.put_line(l_url);


    l_page:=utl_http.request_pieces( l_url, 99999);


    for i in 1..l_page.count loop
    l_response:=l_response||l_page(i);
    end loop;


    n_actual_length:=length(l_response);
    dbms_output.put_line(n_actual_length);
    dbms_output.put_line(l_response);


    --parse JSON result
    json_obj:=new json(l_response);


    l_status := json_ext.get_string(json_obj, 'status');


    IF l_status = 'OK' then





    jl_listOfValues := json_list(json_obj.get('results'));

    json_tempobj := json(jl_listOfValues.get(1));
    json_geom_obj := json(json_tempobj.get(3));

    json_loc := json_ext.get_json(json_geom_obj, 'location');


    l_lat := to_char(json_ext.get_number(json_loc, 'lat'));
    l_lng := to_char(json_ext.get_number(json_loc, 'lng'));
    P_s_Geocoding:=l_lat||','||l_lng;
    dbms_output.put_line('##########'||P_s_Geocoding);



    case json_ext.get_string(json_geom_obj, 'location_type')

    when 'ROOFTOP' then P_n_accuracy:=9;
    when 'RANGE_INTERPOLATED' then P_n_accuracy:=7;
    when 'GEOMETRIC_CENTER' then P_n_accuracy:=5;
    else P_n_accuracy:=3;

    end case;

    P_b_success:=true;



    else


    P_b_success:=false;
    P_n_accuracy:=0;
    P_s_Geocoding:='0,0';

    end if;







  END;
```

Answer (score 2):

The client ID should be included in the path that is signed, and not after the signature is generated.

Try:

```
l_path := '/maps/api/geocode/json?address='||l_address||'&'||'sensor=true'||'&client='||l_client_name;
```

instead of:

```
l_path := '/maps/api/geocode/json?address='||l_address||'&'||'sensor=true';
```

And:

```
l_url:=l_Google_service_domain||l_path||'&signature='||l_signature_b64_alter_back;
```

instead of:

```
l_url:=l_Google_service_domain||l_path||'&client='||l_client_name||'&signature='||l_signature_b64_alter_back;
```